# Get all the connected components from a set of pairs in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column as pairs and other as keys.
I want to create sets of chains of linked indexes:

```
       match1  match2
0          12       5
1          34      12
2          18      29
3          69      31
4          33      34
5.         15     69
```

I'd like to get an output that links all the connected components into lists maybe like this:

```
[12,5,34,33], [18,29], [69, 31, 15]
```

EDIT:
I had tried this earlier.

```
        rev_matches = df[['match1', 'match2']]
        rev_matches['match_list'] = rev_matches.values.tolist()
        rev_matches = rev_matches[['match_list']]
        rev_matches['Key'] = rev_matches.index
        rev_matches = rev_matches.explode('match_list')
        G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(rev_matches, 'match_list', 'Key')
        l = list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

Now this didn't worked out as well. The connections made were inaccurate. Can someone also explain me where is this wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like networkx:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(df[['match1','match2']].to_numpy().tolist())
print(list(nx.connected_components(G)))
#[{5, 12, 33, 34}, {18, 29}, {15, 31, 69}]
```

Comment: Hi thanks. It works.
I have added an edit to my question regarding what i tried with networkx earlier but got inaccurate connection groups. Can you explain where I got it wrong. 
thanks

Comment: @Sushant I am not sure why do you explode to create keys: `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'match1','match2')` would also work ..

Comment: Okay. thanks. I was trying to use the keys to associate it with another dataframe. I'd be pulling values by assigning unique keys to these chained indexes, which are indexes of the other dataframe